# Critical Points of a Complex Sine Function within Bounds

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, optimization

I need a  method to find the critical points of the function below.

```
f(x) = 3.8*sin(2.4*x + 1) - 2.3*sin(7.2*x - 2) + 3.2*sin(8.1*x - 3)
Bounds [-10, 10]
```

I understand I need to set f prime to zero and solve it.

Computed with WolframAlpha, f prime is:

```
25.92 cos(3-8.1 x)-16.56 cos(2-7.2 x)+9.12 cos(1+2.4 x)
```

In the case of sin(x), I know its critical points are located at an **interval of pi * n + pi/2** because **cos(pi*n+pi/2)** is always equal to zero.

But, I'm having trouble calculating a similar interval for the complex sine function above.
Is it even possible?

**My goal is to find all peaks within the bounds of this function.**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the function on the plot. It is quite noisy and there are many peaks which are not evenly distributed. What do you mean by 'numerical results or expected exact'? I'm looking for an exact method to find all the peaks of the function in light of its noisiness. Is it possible?

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for an analytic method to solve for the critical points.

Comment: When you say Mathematica, do you mean the online service on WolframAlpha.com or the software package? Thanks for taking the time to answer btw!